# Confusion regarding resulting shape of a multi-dimensional slicing of a numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy

Suppose we have

```
t = np.random.rand(2,3,4)
```

i.e., a 2x3x4 tensor.

I'm having trouble understanding why the shape of `t[0][:][:2]` is 2x4 rather than 3x2.
Aren't we taking the 0th, all, and the first indices of the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd dimensions, in which case that would give us a 3x2 tensor?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: t = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
In [2]: t
Out[2]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

Select the 1st plane:

```
In [3]: t[0]
Out[3]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

`[:]` selects everything - ie. no change

```
In [4]: t[0][:]
Out[4]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Select first 2 rows of that plane:

```
In [5]: t[0][:][:2]
Out[5]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]])
```

While `[i][j]` works for integer indices, it shouldn't be used for slices or arrays.  Each `[]` acts on the result of the previous.  `[:]` is not a 'placeholder' for the 'middle dimension'.  Python syntax and execution order applies, even when using `numpy`. `numpy` just adds an array class, and functions.  It doesn't change the syntax.

Instead you want:

```
In [6]: t[0,:,:2]
Out[6]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [4, 5],
       [8, 9]])
```

The result is the 1st plane, and first 2 columns, (and all rows).  With all 3 dimensions in one `[]` they are applied in a coordinated manner, not sequentially.

There is a gotcha, when using a slice in the middle of 'advanced indices'.  Same selection as before, but transposed.

```
In [8]: t[0,:,[0,1]]
Out[8]: 
array([[0, 4, 8],
       [1, 5, 9]])
```

For this you need a partial decomposition - applying the `0` first

```
In [9]: t[0][:,[0,1]]
Out[9]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [4, 5],
       [8, 9]])
```

There is a big `indexing` page in the `numpy` docs that you need to study sooner or later.